# Network Printer KONICA MINOLTA BIZHUB 250 cannot print & scan using UBUNTU 18.04LTS

Tags: dual-boot, printing, scanner, konica

Good day. I am currently testing Ubuntu 18.04LTS alongside windows 10. The printer/scanner works in windows 10 but NOT in Ubuntu. I searched this forum but nothing was mentioned specifically about KONICA MINOLTA BIZHUB 250. I searched Ubuntu Software but to no avail. I tried "Google" and found this - "http://www.openprinting.org/printer/KONICA+MINOLTA/KONICA_MINOLTA-bizhub_C250". Is this fine? If yes, could anybody walk me through in installing the right file? I cannot fully understand this - "https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/database/driverpackages". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand this, it is also called the C250; gutenprint, the open-source printer driver in linux; has a driver for this;

If you open the PRINTERS folder; click on the ADD button at top-left; hopefully it sees your bizhub c250; click on that; click FIND DRIVER[image]

then open the Konica folder and look for C250 and click that; [image]

set it and see if it works; the images are from me using the mate version

Comment: hi @pdc. I forgot to tell that the printer is on a windows network. I had tried your idea, but still I cannot print. I had tried booting in windows 10 and everything works well. I revert to ubuntu and again, I cannot print. I had accessed our windows workgroup and am able to access my windows network files using Ubuntu. Only problem is printing/scanning. Any ideas? Thanks by the way for the response.

Comment: then you need to see this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu it says you need samba to talk to the windows server; this is the section of the wiki that details what you need to do: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Ubuntu_print_server please ask if you need further clarification

Comment: Thank you for the link. I was also doing some "googling" on my part and had stumbled upon this - https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-workgroup-ubuntu-linux-work-windows - so I had installed samba. Afterwards, I had read about this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/82016/network-printer-found-but-cannot-print - so I tried to re-install my printer, and viola, it worked like a charm. But now, after reading your link, do I need to really "tweak" my samba installation as stated in your link under "Ubuntu print server compatible with Windows (Samba)" since the printer is working well?

Comment: If it is all working, I would stay quiet!! ...... but you can have a look; if you do `gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf` that allows you to open smb.conf as read-only; you can see if it matches what ubuntu recommends; even if you made changes to the file, they could NOT be saved; to EDIT THE FILE, one would do `gedit admin:///etc/samba/smb.conf`