# Ubuntu printing trouble over the network

Tags: networking, xubuntu, printing

I'm running Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS bionic.
My printer is Canon MX926.
It's connected to a router HUAWEI HG658 via cable and wifi.
My PC is connected via wifi.
Can anyone help me get this printer printing from the computer?
I've referred to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82016/network-printer-found-but-cannot-print) but doesn't work for me.

I looked into the printer network settings on the printer itself and ip is 192.168.1.2. I boldly reset wlan settings which may have been a mistake. But I tried to set up the lan and wlan again on the printer, which seemed to connect to the router with the same IP.

I have these screens:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
The other option in the dropdown is localhost
[image: The other option in the dropdown is localhost]
[image]

No test page will print.
[image: No test pages work]

Do you need more information about this?

Update: trying to install smb4k as per suggestion.

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo apt install smb4k
[sudo] password for user: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo apt install smb4k
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package smb4k
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install smb4k
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package smb4k
user@user-desktop:~$ ^C
user@user-desktop:~$
```

Trying to search Smb4K in Ubuntu Software returns nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is not already done, install Smb4K on your computer. It can greatly help with remote printers. I could not reach my printer until I did that.

Comment: I'm unable to install smb4k. See edited question.

Comment: Smb4K can be easily installed from 'Ubuntu Software' - just type 'Smb4K' to find it.

Comment: Still didn't find it :-( . see update

Comment: Strange. Maybe that helps: https://www.howtoinstall.me/ubuntu/18-04/smb4k/